# Using "onClick()" function inside an ajax function while continue using its success data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

So I want to create an **on click** function after successfully called an **Ajax function**, but I still want to use its original data for that **on click** function.

```
$.ajax({
         URL: ......,
         type: 'GET',
         success: function (res) {
            var Object = JSON.parse(res);
            text = ''

            // some code using Object to fix text

            $('#someid').attr('href', '#')
            $('#someid').text(text)
```

Now what I want is that **someid** item, when clicked on, will create a pop-up, change its original content, or something that continues using the **var Object** up there. I tried but can't find a way to put **on click** into that **Ajax** function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague to me. Please specify what you want to achieve. Im assuming you want to have a function called inside Ajax trigger that consumes Object variable value. If so, it's  feasible for sure by creating a function doClick(ọbject) and then you can invoke it simply by doClick(obj); after making tweaks to Modal popup. But i dare to think there is misunderstanding in your approach. If you could add more details on this, i could suggest you a way to solve the issue.